Break summation of terms in summations of each term
I am trying to break the summation over two terms in two summations for each term, that is:
From \begin{align}\sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2(-t_{l}t_{x} + t_{l}^2t_{x})&\end{align} to \begin{align}\sum\limits_{l}^{L}-a_{l}^2t_{l}t_{x} + \sum\limits_{l}^{L}a_{l}^2t_{l}^2t_{x}&\end{align}
This is how I would write the first expression in Mathematica:
Sum[Subscript[a, l]^2(- Subscript[t, l]  Subscript[t, x] + (Subscript[t, l]^2 Subscript[t, x])), {l,L}]

What would be the command in Mathematica to expand the summation as showed above?

Use Distribute, optionally with Expand.
Distribute@Sum[Subscript[a, l]^2(- Subscript[t, l]  Subscript[t, x] + 
  (Subscript[t, l]^2 Subscript[t, x])) // Expand, {l,L}]

$$\sum_l^L -a_l^2 t_l t_x+\sum _l^L a_l^2 t_l^2 t_x$$

Alright, this worked indeed. However, I noticed that when I also include the term $a_{l}$ as shown in my updated question,  Distribute does now work anymore.

Yes, it works on direct separate terms. Use Expand prior to Distribute.
